# The value of attribute "translatable" associated with an element type "string" must not contain the '<' character. error

Tags: java, android, layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <string name="firebase_url">[YOUR_FIREBASE_URL]</string>
        <!--Your Google Place API from your developers.google.com setting. Take a look on https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/-->
        <string name="AIza..." translatable="false”>[YOUR_GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY]</string>

        <!--Your Google Banner Id from your admob setting. Take a look on https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start-->
        <string name="admob_app_id" translatable="false">[YOUR_GOOGLE_ADMOB_APP_ID]</string>
        <string name="about_banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">[YOUR_GOOGLE_ADMOB_UNIT_ID]</string>
        <string name="profile_banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">[YOUR_GOOGLE_ADMOB_UNIT_ID]</string>

        <!--Your Google Place API from your developers.facebook.com setting. Take a look on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_id}/dashboard/-->
        <string name="facebook_app_id">[YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID]</string>
        <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">[YOUR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_SCHEME]</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <string name="AIza..." translatable="false”>[YOUR_GOOGLE_PLACE_API_KEY]</string>
> ```

Replace the `”` unicode right double quote with regular ascii quote `"`.

Also it looks like you've put a value where a key would be expected. I've redacted your API key from this answer. Consider renewing your API keys since they are no longer secret.